# jquery ui dragging over iframe lost the drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, web

When make a fast dragging of an element when it is over an iframe the element lost the drag...

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pedrodsa/m9kveakv/1/

```
<h3>Pick a number on the SIDE MENU and drag t inside the iframe. Then make a fast drag (in order the mouse goes out the number div area)</h3>

<div class="container">
    <div class="side-menu">
        SIDE MENU
        <ul id="draggable">
          <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
          <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">

        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: if you drag slowly its working right...

Comment: Its hard to explains this to the client... :(  (this is not a option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( "#draggable li" ).draggable({
     revert: true,
     iframeFix: true

 });
```

Try this... this is working....

Answer (score 0):

Checked it, The thing is that the drag work as long as the mouse pointer stays on the number, once the mouse pointer loses focus of the number, the number loses the drag. 
You need to find a way to keep the mouse pointer focused on the number, or else to make the numbers drag able even when they lose focus.

Comment: there the jquery event focus, read a bit about it an see if it fits your needs. basically it binds to focus event to the element of your wish, most people use it to focus on text box or text area for emphasis of important fields but it might suite your needs as well